# Bltoolkit - Dealing with identity with multiple db's

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, bltoolkit

How do I deal with identity when I'm supporting multiple db's with Bltoolkit. I know that BL supports InsertWithIdentity call with linq whne doing inserts, but I think it only works with Sql Server and in this instance I don't want to use it in this instance

Is their a better way doing. Pehaps creating some kind of identity map to store the last primary key value for a particular entity stored.

Any advice would be helpful.
Thanks
scope_creep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql supports AUTO_INCREMENT, so it's not a problem.

For Oracle there are two ways to implement identity:

1. Define a [trigger](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/master/Data/Create%20Scripts/Oracle.sql#L79).
2. Use a [sequence](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/master/UnitTests/Linq/Model/Person.cs#L28).

Comment: @It, Is that the official bltoolkit line.

Comment: @IT, also would bltoolkit support the following:- insert into test values(test_seq.nextval, 'test'); from a DataAccessor.

Comment: This is code from BLToolkit unit test project. It's quite official.